# C++ compare a byte to a letter

Tags: c++, compare, byte

I have serial data I want to compare a specific byte to the letter "G".

LPtype is a byte that was read from the serial port.

```
if (LPtype == "G")
{
    doThis();
}
```

I get the following error:

C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer

What would be the proper way of comparing the incoming bye to the letter G? (or any other letter for that matter)

Comment: Lets see the type of `LPtype`.

Comment: `LPtype is a byte` Is it? Really? Seems like a strange name for a byte.

Comment: Does whatever type `LPtype` is have an `operator==(const char *)`? If so, does it do what you want done here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
LPtype == 'G'
```

Singular quotes. But LP usually prefixes pointer types, in which case you should dereference it

```
*LPtype == 'G'
```

But if you're sure LPtype is indeed a byte value, then

```
LPtype == 'G'
```

should work. The thing is that `"G"` has type `const char[2]`, and is not an integer type, whereas `'G'` has type `char` and is integer type

Comment: I don't think encouraging the OP to guess wildly is a particularly responsible thing to do, Armen, even if you're only doing it implicitly by guessing wildly yourself ;)

Comment: "But LP usually prefixes pointer types, in which case you should dereference it: `*LPtype == 'G'`" - in this case, the compiler wouldn't have complained about integer and pointer comparison...

Comment: it was the quotes, thank you, i have not done much C++, mostly VB so alot of mistakes from me. as for the LPtype , i am polling and the LP was for Last Poll , and type was the type of poll, didnt know that would cause issues

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
  LPtype == 'G'
```